# No se me aplica estilo a etiqueta HTML desde HTML

Tags: html

Estoy intentando modificar los estilos desde la etiqueta HTML si el usuario ha iniciado sesión. Lo uso mucho en la web y no me da problemas, pero en este caso no consigo que se apliquen:

```
<h1 <?php if($user != "null") { echo "style='borderLeft: 5px solid #" . $usuario_color['color_principal'] . "'";} ?>>Título</h1>
```

El código que me genera es el siguiente:

```
<h1 style="borderLeft: 5px solid #007AFF">Título</h1>
```

No encuentro el fallo, he probado también añadiendo `;` al final del código del color, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: En Javascript las propiedades de CSS se contraen pero en el propio CSS suelen ir separadas por un guión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al utilizarlo en la definición de estilos el nombre de la propiedad es `border-left`:

```html
<h1 style="border-left: 5px solid #007AFF">Título</h1>
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Tenía entendido que los guiones tenía que quitarlos. ¡Valido tu respuesta ahora cuando me lo permita!